# Bazel cuda_add_executable equivalent?

Tags: build, bazel, nvcc

I was exploring using Bazel instead of cmake for building a project.  Is there something equivalent to "cuda_add_executable" or "cuda_add_library" in cmake?

cc_library doesn't appear to allow ".cu" extensions, so that would require a rename of those files, and looking through the tensorflow repo, it's not entirely clear to me how nvcc might be enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such rule provided by the Bazel team. However you can build one using our [extension language](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html). Tensorflow does a bit different. It [configure a crosstool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl) and pass it .cc files.